# Почему хранимая процедура MySql игнорирует наличие where

Tags: mysql, хранимые-процедуры

Работаю через OpenServer 5.3.7
Apache 2.4-PHP7.4, Php 7.4, mysql-8.0
Создаю хранимую процедуру:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`invest`@`%` PROCEDURE `test`(IN `tiket` VARCHAR(20) CHARSET utf8)
    MODIFIES SQL DATA
BEGIN
set @tiket = tiket;
select `id_company` from `Company` where `tiket` = @tiket;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

При её выполнении чтобы я не подавала на вход, он мне выдаёт полное содержание таблицы, как будто игнорирую условия where.
Даже ума не приложу куда копать, может кто может подсказать.

Comment: `\`tiket\`` - это переменная. А вот `\`Company\`.\`tiket\`` - это поле таблицы. Одноимённая переменная имеет приоритет и маскирует поле. Так что Вы сравниваете два заведомо равных (с учётом присвоения на строку выше) значения. Поэтому выводится всё (был бы параметр равен NULL - не вывелось бы ничего).

Comment: Спасибо большое всё получилось.